# Python Selenium 2 iFrames in one page

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to fill in the sign up form in this website : https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en

There is 2 iframes, one for the username and the other for recovery email

When i switch to username, i become able to sendkeys to username but not for recovery email. and when i switch to username i don't know how to switch back to recovery

```
    driver.get("https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en")
    newproton = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='Registration form']")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password']").send_keys('test')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='passwordc']").send_keys('test')
    driver.switch_to.frame(newproton[0])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='username']").send_keys('username')
    driver.switch_to.frame(newproton[1])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='notificationEmail']").send_keys('recoveryemail')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(newproton[1])
```

you have to first switch out of the first iframe , you can do it by using `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: That worked perfectly !!!
Can you please fill in the information manually and check the second page, we have 4 choices, i want to choose sms and same thing there is about 5 iframes but no one is for the sms part, and also i tried to set it back to default content

Comment: If I frame is with in Iframe you have to go to first frame then to next frame , if the third frame is in same level as second then go to parent frame that is second frame